# Does Spring's DispatcherServlet shows any influence on HttpSession by default for its timeout?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I've been working on a Web based Application on Spring MVC architecture. With the Java EE applications, I'm very much familiar that HttpSession can be timed out in either of these three ways

1. Invoking invalidate method(generally while logging out).
2. Setting session time out in web.xml.
3. Web server itself destroyes sessions objects when heap memory exceeds.

But in my Spring application, HttpSession gets timed out after I make my application idle for several hours eventhough none of the above reasons were causes. I really have no idea what is causing this.

Comment: if session timeout is not defined in web.xml, it may be inherited from global application server configuration. For instance Tomcat have a default session timeout of 30 minutes

Comment: @ben75 I'm using tomcat only. So, Can I change configuration in my tomcat, where I can restrict inheritance of session from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default session timeout in tomcat is defined in

```
<TOMCAT_HOME>/conf/web.xml
```

All configuration parameters of this file can be overridden in web.xml of the webapp.

If you need an infinite session timeout use `-1` :

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```